Fargate Max CPU and Memory Utilisation
This is a nodeJS application hosted on AWS Fargate. As what infer from the graph, the max CPU and memory utlisation is around 2.5x to 3x of the average cpu/memory utilisation.
My question is:

Am I over provision my fargate resource?
if I tune down the CPU and memory by half, and max CPU/Memory Utilisation hit 100%, but average CPU/memory utilisation be around 50-70%, will it cause the application to crash/restart, or have impact on performance when max CPU/memory hit 100%?



From the graphs, it's clear that your peak CPU and memory usage is about 2.5x to 3x higher than the average, meaning your resources are likely underutilized most of the time. This suggests you may be over-provisioning.
If you reduce CPU and memory by half, and the application hits 100% utilization during peak times, performance could be impacted. CPU at 100% may slow down response times or cause unresponsiveness, while memory at 100% could result in crashes or OOM errors, depending on how your app handles memory limits.
In short, hitting 100% utilization during peaks could lead to performance issues or crashes. My recommendation is to reduce resources incrementally and monitor the impact to ensure performance remains stable.
